# Google plus one button

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-plus-one

look at my blog's index page http://www.lowcoupling.com
for each post I'd like to show the number of plus 1 the post received.
I understand I need to use the URL to plus 1 but I can't see how
considering

```
<!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="tall"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include href="*url*" in each div

Source:
https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/#tag_parameters